# Visual Studio header file use

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I've been programming for years in C and I'm now starting on some C++/CLR projects in visual studio. Something that confuses me is the way the designer is adding stuff in the header file of your main form. For instance if you have a button in the designer, double click it, then the designer will add the event function in the header file. I always learned not to code in header files. Or am I missing some clues? Any of you guys have some best practcve rules on this subject?

Thanks

Comment: Some concrete questions. The designer creates a 
**private: System::Void pictureBox1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {}**
function in the Form1.h file. Should I remove the brackets, make it a function prototype and code in the .cpp file? Can I maybe show the designer to create these functions directly in the .cpp file?Or can I just start to code in the .h file?